# Should I handle developer failure with returning null or throw custom execption

Tags: c#, .net, exception

When a developer passes a resourceKey which does not exist I catch his failure by using the 'as' operator

**option1**:

```
  var image = resourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey) as Bitmap;
   return image;
```

**option2**

```
var image = resourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey) as Bitmap
```

Should I null check here and throw custom execption("image for given key does not exist!")

I "assume" every developer test his code so passing a **non-existing** resourcekey as a string should result in a Exception by the GetObject-Method call.

What benefit does the developer has when he just returns null and nothing is shown? Actually no benefit.

But my colleagues are different opinion...

Comment: Not answering your question but I think you should check the resource object first before casting it as `Bitmap`.

Comment: There are a few golden rules with exceptions.  
One is not to use exceptions for things you can handle otherwise, since catch blocks are performance killers.  
Another one is not to use exceptions as flow control. 
Linvi's answer second option a good solution for these cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I experienced the same problem when implementing a public library.

I think it usually better to ensure that the developers know what they doe. If a value can be null or throw an exception he needs to be aware of this.

The method says `GetBitmap`, it doesn't say `PleaseTryGetBitmap` or `FindBitmap` (*find* implies that something may not be found). Thus the contract of the method explicitly say that a bitmap should be fetched for the given name. Any thing else is an exceptional case and an exception should therefore be thrown.

So I would suggest 2 solutions for your problem:

**1. Throw an exception and add a `<exception>` to document your method.**

Include the key that failed in your thrown exception. It makes debugging a lot easier.

```
/// <exception cref="ArgumentException"></exception>
public Bitmap GetBitmap(string resourceKey)
{
    var bitmap = resourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey) as Bitmap;
    if (bitmap == null) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("resourceKey", resourceKey, "Failed to find resource with the specified name.");
    return bitmap != null;
}
```

**2. Use a `tryGet` style method as followed.**

This will enforce the developers to check whether the value does exist and act based on this.

```
public bool TryGetBitmap(string resourceKey, out Bitmap bitmap)
{
    bitmap = resourceManager.GetObject(resourceKey) as Bitmap;
    return bitmap != null;
}
```

Comment: You'd probably want to *rename* the method into `TryGetBitmap` or return `Image` instead of `Bitmap`

Comment: Added the first example. +1 :)

Comment: I think you should "return bitmap;" in your first example